# Google Maps API returning lat/long but error not getting caught

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Reading that title it's probably confusing as to what's going on....I agree.

So I have an address that I want to show on a Google Map. I don't have the lat/long so I need to call the Geocoder service provided by the Google Maps API.

When I request the lat/long for an address, the service is returning a legitimate value, but when stepping through the javascript on the last line in the geocode function, the code goes off into the geocoder.js minified code and never returns (no successful result, no exception).

I've done lots of research on using the Google Maps API, and as far as I can tell, I've implemented exactly how the examples show. Where am I going wrong here?

Here's the javascript code that calls the lat/long service:

```
function getLatLong(street, city, state, zip) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var address = street && street.length > 0 ? street + ' ' : '';
    address += city && city.length > 0 ? city + ', ' : '';
    address += state && state.length > 0 ? state + ' ' : '';
    address += zip && zip.length > 0 ? zip : '';

    var latLong = {
        lat: 0.0,
        long: 0.0
    };

    try {
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : address }, function(results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                return {
                    lat: results[0].geometry.location.lat(),
                    long: results[0].geometry.location.lng()
                };
            } else {
                return latLong;
            }
        });
    } catch (exception) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

(If you don't want to step through, it's "getting lost" on the line above the `catch` in the code above)

And if you want to see it in action and step through for yourself, here's the URL: http://golfproxy.com/course/list

Edit: If it helps, here's the function that adds the map and markers, which calls the getLatLong function above:

```
function plotMapHardCodePos(position) {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 9,
        center: position
    });

    $.each(tournaments.Result, function (i, item) {
        var latLong = {};

        if (!item.Latitude || !item.Longitude) {
            latLong = getLatLong(item.Street, item.City, item.State, item.ZipCode);

            if (latLong) {
                item.Latitude = latLong.lat;
                item.Longitude = latLong.long;
            }
        }

        if (!(item.Latitude === 0.0 && item.Longitude === 0.0)) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(item.Latitude, item.Longitude),
                map: map
            });

            marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');

            var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<div class=''><h4><a href=\"#\">" + item.Name + "</a></h4></div><br/><span>" +
                    item.Body1 + "</span>" + "<br/><span>" + item.Body2 + "</span>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function, you need to use the data in the callback function when/where it is available

Comment: Not sure why this is worthy of a downvote, but thanks for answering @geocodezip

Comment: @geocodezip it works now, thank you!

Comment: @geocodezip can you add your comment as an answer so I can give you credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return anything from an asynchronous callback function, you need to use the data in the callback function when/where it is available